# In .NET Core MVC, how do I access the DbContext while inside an AuthorizationHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here is my startup code to configure services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDbContext<ThisApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddAuthentication(
        SharedOptions => SharedOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    services.AddAuthorization(
         options => { options.AddPolicy("ValidUsers",
             policy =>
             {
                policy.Requirements.Add(new ValidUserAuthorization());
             });
         });
}
```

And here is the class for authorizing users:

```
public class ValidUserAuthorization : AuthorizationHandler<ValidUserAuthorization>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ValidUserAuthorization requirement)
    {
        string username = context.User.Identity.Name;

        if (context.User.Identity.Name == "hardcoded-username")
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I would like to change my authorization class (`ValidUserAuthorization`) to be able to look up the username in my application database (as accessed via `ThisApplicationDbContext`), rather than comparing against hard-coded strings.

What is the best way of obtaining this database context (as already initialized in `ConfigureServices`) and having the authorization class use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way of doing it is by passing the type of your DbContext as a generic type:

```
public class ValidUserAuthorization<TDbContext> : AuthorizationHandler<ValidUserAuthorization>, IAuthorizationRequirement
    where TDbContext : DbContext, new()
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ValidUserAuthorization requirement)
    {
        using (TDbContext db = new TDbContext())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create the `ValidUserAuthorization` object like this in your `ConfigureServices` method:

```
policy.Requirements.Add(new ValidUserAuthorization<ThisApplicationDbContext>());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really like this method. Reading your answer made me realise that it could also be passed in as a parameter to the constructor. I don't know which one would be a better practice though - what do you think?

Comment: It would work too but it would require reflection to invoke the constructor. This works perfectly but it is a little bit slower to execute. In my projects I try to use generic types when possible and reflection otherwise, but both methods are good so you can go as you please.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about reflection aspect of that - thanks. Turns out I couldn't find an instantiated ThisApplicationDbContext object to supply to the authorization handler, so I'll have to try to figure out some other way anyway. Quite new to this MVC framework!

Comment: Oh, I was thinking that you wanted to pass the type of your `DbContext` as a parameter but apparently you want to pass the DbContext itself. I strongly discourage you to do that unless you know what you are doing because the object being passed as a parameter may have been disposed or may be sending an async query, which would raise an error when you try to use it. I think it is better to use a new DbContext once and dispose it just after.